Extension of scalars for bounded chain complexes of $kG$-modules
I'm wondering if a generalization regarding a statement from Curtis-Reiner holds. The original statement is as follows:
(30.33) Theorem: Let $R$ and $S$ be complete discrete valuation rings, with $S$ an extension of $R$, and suppose that $R/J(R)$ is a finite field. Then for each indecomposable finitely generated $A$-module $M$, the $SA = S\otimes_R A$-module $SM$ is a direct sum of non-isomorphic indecomposable submodules.
I'd like to know if an analogous statement holds for bounded chain complexes rather than (f.g.) modules. The case I'm particularly interested in is when $R = kG$ and $S = k'G$, where $k'/k$ is an extension of finite fields and $G$ is a finite group. Going through the proof of this theorem, I don't know if the following isomorphism holds anymore: $\operatorname{Hom}_{k'G}(k'\otimes_k C,k' \otimes_k D) \cong k' \otimes_k \operatorname{Hom}_{kG}(C,D)$ where $C$ and $D$ are bounded chain complexes of $kG$-modules (see CR Theorem (2.38) for the module-theoretic statement).
Also, if anyone knows what "MO 2e" refers to in Theorem (2.38) of CR, please let me know. Thank you! (edit: it refers to Irving Reiner's "Maximal Orders," thank you Dave!)

MO refers to "Maximal Orders" by Irv Reiner.

Since $k'$ is finite dimensional over $k$, you can move it from inside to outside a Hom in the last isomorphism below. $$\operatorname{\rm Hom}_{k'G}(k'\otimes_k C,k'\otimes_k D)\cong \operatorname{\rm Hom}_{kG}(C,\operatorname{\rm Hom}_{k'}(k',k'\otimes_k D))$$ $$=\operatorname{\rm Hom}_{kG}(C,k'\otimes_k D)\cong k'\otimes_k \operatorname{\rm Hom}_{kG}(C,D). $$ If $k'$ is not finite dimensional over $k$, it is this last step that fails.

Thank you so much Dave! Ack, should have known to try tensor-hom.
I believe that since this is true, it may be possible to follow Reiner's proof of (30.33).
